# C++17 custom iterator in a pimpl idiom context

Tags: c++, iterator, implementation, pimpl-idiom, c++17

I want to know how to have a c++ class to be iterable (stl compatible) without exposing the implementation ?

The structure of the project is like :

**`Stream`**

```
class Stream
{
public:
    Stream();

    [...]

    StreamIterator iter()
    {
        return StreamIterator(this);
    }

private:
    class impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> pimpl;
};
```

**`StreamFilter`**

```
class StreamFilter
{
public:
    StreamFilter();

    [...]

private:
    class impl;
    std::shared_ptr<impl> pimpl;
};
```

**`StreamIterator`**

```
class StreamIterator
{
public:
    StreamIterator(Stream* streamToFilter);

    [...]

    void addFilter(StreamFilter* filter);
    void removeFilter(StreamFilter* filter);

    [...]

private:
    class impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> pimpl;
};
```

**`StreamFilter`** is a base class for differents filtering strategies.

For simplicity in the sample code, I used raw memory pointers, of course in a real exploitation code I use intelligents pointers : shared, weak ...

I want to allow the **`StreamIterator`** become iterable in a STL way, doing :

```
StreamIterator iter = stream.iter();
iter.addFilter(new FilterByOffset([...with parameters...]));
for (auto item : iter)
{
    [...doing something with filtered items...]
}
```

The basic way is to add some accessors to allow range-based for loop.

**`StreamIterator`**

```
class StreamIterator
{
public:
    StreamIterator(Stream* streamToFilter);

    [...]

    iterator begin();
    iterator end();

    const_iterator cbegin() const;
    const_iterator cend() const;

    [...]

    void addFilter(StreamFilter* filter);
    void removeFilter(StreamFilter* filter);

    [...]

private:
    class impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> pimpl;
};
```

Where **`iterator`** and **`const_iterator`** are basically typedef's to the internal container iterators. And this is the problem.

First, I don't want to expose private implementation in the **`StreamIterator`** header. And so, **`iterator`** and **`const_iterator`** are not allowed here.

Second, because of the stream filtering strategy, the iterators returned are not just alias to some internal stl containers. In the internal implementation, I need to call the filters in a functor way to check if the item need to be exclude or not.

The only type allowed in the **`StreamIterator`** header is the type of the item object returned.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you very much!

**Additional Information**:

Maybe this declaration is a way to allow a private implementation, I need to investigate more :

**`StreamIterator`**

```
class StreamIterator
{
public:
    StreamIterator(Stream* streamToFilter);

    [...]

    struct iterator
    {
        Object::Ptr operator*();
        iterator& operator++();
        bool operator!= (const iterator& it) const;
    };

    typedef typename StreamIterator::iterator iterator;

    iterator begin();
    iterator end();

    [...]

    void addFilter(StreamFilter* filter);
    void removeFilter(StreamFilter* filter);

    [...]

private:
    class impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> pimpl;
};
```

Comment: "Iterators" should be sufficiently simple that they don't need to be using Pimpl.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas - Yes, this is basically a forward iterator, so this type of definition can be easily implement in the cpp file like a wrapper to my internal code.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. Doing what you want has a *substantial cost* associated with it. Every separate `StreamIterator` instance needs to dynamically allocate memory. Most interfaces that take iterators copy them around frequently because they're not expected to be expensive to copy. And every copy of a Pimpl type will need to dynamically allocate memory. Whatever private implementation you're trying to hide is not worth the *cost* you have to incur in order to successfully hide it. Also, your `StreamIterator` is not an STL-compatible iterator; it's a *range*.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas - OK, I see. In all case, the "additional information" implementation is wrong. So what do you mean about the "range" instead the iterator and how to implement that for range-based loop in this type of context? Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Roughly speaking, a "range" is a thing that *has* begin/end iterators. STL iterators don't know where they start or stop; that's why iterator-based interfaces take them in pairs. What you call `StreamIterator` is conceptually more of a `StreamView`: a reference to an existing `Stream` that is filtered in some way.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't call it `StreamIterator`; an iterator is a pointer-like object for which 2 of them can specify a range.  Your `StreamIterator` doesn't have this.  Nothing good can come of reusing the well defined iterator term here.

---

Now, your `StreamIterator` is some kind of *range* of iterators.  So we'll call it a `StreamRange`.

In order to hide how `StreamRange` can be iterated over, you have to hide how the iterators it uses work.

And this -- hiding the implementation detalis of a stream iterator -- has a substantial cost to it.

When iterating over a loop, each step in the loop involves `++` and `*` and an `==`.  Throwing a pointer indirection and a vtable lookup (or equivalent) on each of those will make your loops much slower.

But here is how to do it.

```
template<class Value>
struct any_input_iterator {
  using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
  using value_type=Value;
  using pointer = value_type*;
  using reference = value_type;
  using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

private:
  struct vtable_t {
    bool(*equal)( std::any const& lhs, std::any const& rhs ) = 0;
    Value(*get)( std::any& ) = 0;
    void(*inc)( std::any& ) = 0;
  };
  vtable_t const* vtable = 0;
  std::any state;

  template<class U>
  static vtable_t make_vtable() {
    return {
      [](std::any const& lhs, std::any const& rhs)->bool {
        return std::any_cast<U const&>(lhs) == std::any_cast<U const&>(rhs);
      },
      [](std::any& src)->Value {
        return *std::any_cast<U&>(src);
      },
      [](std::any& src) {
        ++std::any_cast<U&>(src);
      }
    };
  }
  template<class U>
  static vtable_t const* get_vtable() {
    static const auto vtable = make_vtable<U>();
    return &vtable;
  }
public:
  template<class U,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<U>, any_input_iterator>{}, bool> = true
  >
  any_input_iterator(U&& u):
    vtable(get_vtable<std::decay_t<U>>()),
    state(std::forward<U>(u))
  {}

  any_input_iterator& operator++() { vtable->inc(state); return *this; }
  any_input_iterator operator++(int) { auto tmp = *this; ++*this; return tmp; }
  reference operator*() { return vtable->get(state); }
  friend bool operator==( any_input_iterator const& lhs, any_input_iterator const& rhs ) {
    if (lhs.vtable != rhs.vtable) return false;
    if (!lhs.vtable) return true;
    return lhs.vtable->equal( lhs.state, rhs.state );
  }
  friend bool operator!=( any_input_iterator const& lhs, any_input_iterator const& rhs ) {
    return !(lhs==rhs);
  }

  struct fake_ptr {
    Value t;
    Value* operator->()&&{ return std::addressof(t); }
  };

  fake_ptr operator->()const { return {**this}; }
};
```

there are probably some typoes, but this is basic type erasure.  Boost does a better job at this.

I only supported input iterators.  If you want to support forward iterators, you have to change up some typedefs and return references and the like.

```
any_input_iterator<int> begin();
any_input_iterator<int> end();
```

that is, however, enough to let someone iterate over your range in question.

It will be slow, but it will work.